# Extracting year from the name of the file from the last index before the extention in python

Tags: python, file, split

I am trying the extract the year from the file name.
I have files, named as

`godzilla_2012.txt`

`king_arthur_legend_of_the_sword_2016.txt`

`Teenage_Mutant_ninja_turtle_2017.txt`

I want to extract the year from the name of the file, for example

`2012`

`2016`

and so on

Comment: Use a regular expression for this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = ["godzilla_2012.txt", "king_arthur_legend_of_the_sword_2016.txt", "Teenage_Mutant_ninja_turtle_2017.txt"]
years = [re.findall(r'(\d{4})\.\w+$', x)[0] for x in inp]
print(years)  # ['2012', '2016', '2017']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for one case. You can use iteratively afterwards, if you want to use it for multiple statements.

```py
statement = 'king_arthur_legend_of_the_sword_2016.txt'
year = statement.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always that format, you can use `filename.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]`. That will give the string; if you want it as an integer, you can do `int(filename.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0])`.

Regular expressions are more powerful and can let you handle a wider variety of formats, but that could be a bad thing. For instance, if you have a regular expression looking for any numeric characters, it will pick up the `1984` in `wonder_woman_1984_2020.txt` and the `2001` in `2001_a_space_odyssey_1968.txt`.

Comment: It appears that [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9939456/gabrielp) has already provided this solution.

Comment: thank you for this, it's a very detailed example and might counter it in future with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the year by this method if file_name has no number before the year as in your file

```
file = "file6655"
n = 0
li = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
for i in file:
    if i in li:
        n = n + 1
        if n == 1:
            year = i
        if n > 1:
            year = year + i
        print(year)
```

output of this will be 6655.
For multiple files in folder you can use os module